# VS2013 and Silverlight 5 "Unable to disable loading of ngen images from app-local native image cache"

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2013, silverlight-5.0, iis-express

I've been working on a Silverlight 5 app for some time now and I've recently installed VS2013 on a Win8.1 update machine. Every time I compile and run my app on that machine the debugger breaks into the iisexpress code without any message or indication of an exception if I press run again then the app executes normally without incident. The project runs ok on VS2012. Any idea on why this is happening?
EDIT: I'm receiving this error: "Unable to disable loading of ngen images from app-local native image cache"

Thanks,

Juan Carlos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having the same problem, I managed to find a workaround for this:
I disabled the Native code debugger in the web tab in the web project property page; that stopped the debugger from jumping into the IIS code.